# Please review my proof.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I am working on a problem from Spivak 13.7 which states:

Prove:

$$m_i'' + m_i' \leq m_i$$

Where:

$$m_i'' = \inf \{f(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i\}$$
$$m_i' = \inf \{g(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i\}$$
$$m_i = \inf \{(f+g)(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i\}$$

I have posted my solution to the proof down below as suggested by [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3589/is-it-ok-to-ask-whether-my-proof-solution-is-correct-if-i-dont-have-any-particu).

Comment: I have a small objection to this in the sense that one could ask questions to which they know the answer in order to rack up reputation points.

Comment: I'll make it a community wiki then?

Comment: Give me a sec trying to remember how to do that.

Comment: As for your answer, it is somewhat confusing. I'll post my solution below.

Comment: Anyone know where the community wiki button? Can't find it...

Comment: @ChrisK: Found the community wiki button for the answer, don't know where it is for the question though...

Comment: I'm not sure about the community wiki. As for your proof, the main points are there. As it's chapter 13, the rigour in my proof is not really necessary (material from Chapter 8 isn't it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we let $\inf f, \inf g, \inf (f+g)$ and $I$ be the interval.

We have that $\inf f + \inf g \leq f(t) + g(t) = (f+g)(t)$ $\forall t \in I$.

Now, suppose $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall t>0$, $f(t) + g(t) - \inf(f+g) \geq \epsilon$. Then we have that $\inf(f+g) + \epsilon \leq f(t) + g(t)\; \forall t>0$. But this is a contradiction since an infimum is the greatest lower bound. So, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists t \in I$ such that $f(t)+g(t) - \inf(f+g) < \epsilon$ and so $f(t) + g(t) < \inf(f+g) + \epsilon$ for some $t \in I$.

So, choose t as required yielding: $\inf f + \inf g \leq f(t) + g(t) \leq \inf(f+g) + \epsilon$. Now suppose $\inf(f+g) < \inf f + \inf g$, then choose $\epsilon = \frac{\inf f + \inf g - \inf(f+g)}{2}$ which gives a contradiction. This completes the proof.

This is really an exercise in infimums. In further analysis courses, something like this would be taken as 'obvious'.

Comment: Thanks, I am still a little confused as to why choosing $\epsilon = \frac{\inf{f} + \inf{g} - \inf{(f+g)}}{2}$ leads to a contradiction though.

Comment: Well... we have that $\inf f + \inf g \leq \inf(f+g) + \epsilon$ from above. Now, we have $\inf f + \inf g \leq \inf(f+g) + \frac{\inf f + \inf g - \inf(f+g)}{2}$ which implies $\frac{\inf f + \inf g}{2} \leq \frac{\inf(f+g)}{2}$. But this goes against our assumption.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(f+g)(a) = m_i$, $f(a') = m_i'$, and $g(a'') = m_i''$. Then either $a = a' = a''$, in which case we have:

$$ f(a) + g(a) = (f + g)(a)$$
$$ f(a) + g(a) = f(a) + g(a)$$

(Valid step? $(f+g)(a) = f(a) + g(a)$)

which means, in this case:

$$ m_i'' + m_i' = m_i$$

Then we have the case where one or more of $a$, $a'$ or $a''$ differ. In this case:

$$f(a') + g(a'') = (f + g)(a)$$
$$f(a') + g(a'') = f(a) + g(a)$$

In the case that $f(a) \neq f(a')$, $f(a')$ must be $\leq f(a)$ since $f(a')$ is the infininum of $f$ within the specified interval.

In the case that $g(a) \neq g(a'')$, $g(a'')$ must be $\leq g(a)$ since $g(a'')$ is the infininum of $g$ within the specified interval.

Finally, if none equals one another, then we have already shown that in both case both $g(a)$ and $f(a)$ must be $\geq g(a'')$, $f(a')$.